# Infinite ring with nonzero characteristic

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I was wondering as I read about characteristic of a ring: Is there an infinite ring with nonzero characteristic? We have $1+1+\ldots+1=0$, but that doesn't seem to imply that the number of elements in the ring is finite.

Comment: cf. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356649/can-a-ring-of-positive-characteristic-have-infinite-number-of-elements

Comment: It is $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ as in the field of p elements $F_p$. The polynomial ring $F_p[x]$ has infinitely many elements, but characteristic p.

Comment: These are the polynomials with coefficients in  $\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$. Other examples are the polynomial rings K[X] in X over any finite field K.

Comment: Thanks @rschwieb and gammatester

Comment: The algebraic closure of any finite field is infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, like the polynomial rings $F[x]$ where $F$ is a finite field.  Then we also have $F(x)$ and $F[[x]]$.  The list goes on . . ..

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***